# Implement sign out from google Oauth

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

How to sign out from sign-in-with-google app. I want to sign out in such a way that it again ask for password when again sign in with google.
I don't want to remove account from my browser.
I just simply want to forget my browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
<script>
  function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
      console.log('User signed out.');
    });
  }
</script>
```

Its from the official document https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#sign_out_a_user.

If you want to logout of an application as a user of any website you can do it in your account's security preferences: https://myaccount.google.com/permissions